# Can I upload an app into playstore with starter edition of Xamarin studio?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have developed a sample app using Xamarin studio for android. But the build(apk file) will work only for 1 day. I am using trial version of xamarin studio. Please let me know if I can upload the app into play store with starter edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there you go, you can deploy but there is a limit on package size,
please go through [Pricing page](http://xamarin.com/faq#pricing),

Quoted

> Xamarin Starter allows developers to build and publish simple apps, which contain no more than 64k of compiled user code (IL), and which do not call out to native third party libraries (i.e., developers may not P/Invoke into C/C++/Objective-C/Java.

also for details about the package , you can head to this [Discussion page](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2912/xamarin-starter-edition-build-limits)

Comment: I have an academic license for Xamarin. Can I upload my Mono apps on Google store ? if yes then what are the project size limitations ?

Comment: @جمشیدکامران Yes, you can upload apps to play store.
Regarding app size limitation, it seems there is no limitation as such.
Kindly refer to following links for more details:
1) https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42770/commercial-use-of-student-license
2) https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/

Comment: Well Thank you @Biswajeet

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can publish your app to the Google Play store. If you go to http://xamarin.com/starter and scroll down (as of this printing), you can find three apps which are published to iOS and Android app stores using Xamarin Starter.

Here's one sample, ["Days Until Xmas"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrisntr.daysuntilxmasandroid)

Xamarin Starter was recently expanded to allow creation of apps up to 128 KB in Intermediate Language (IL), but you cannot add 3rd party libraries to your apps with Starter.

Your apps will need to be relatively simple apps if you wish to remain under the 128 KB IL limit.

Answer (score 0):

regarding this discussion: [Xamarin starter edition - deploy to market](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6458/can-i-deploy-an-app-using-xamarin-at-no-cost), you should be able to deploy your app to store.

**Edit:** Oh sorry, I just checked again and you are interested in trial, not starter edition. In case of the trial edition, which has 24-hour restriction, you wont be able to publish it on Google play store, since the submission process of application to Google play takes from 1-3 days.

Comment: I m using trial version. But I want know if I can deploy using starter edition

Comment: Well yes, if you develop your application under starter edition (which is limited to 64 Kb of user code), you can deploy it to Google Play.